# Finding a closed form for $\frac{1}{10}+\frac{2}{10^2}+\frac{3}{10^3}+\frac{4}{10^4}+\cdots$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the expected value of a random variable $X = k$ with probability mass function $0.1^k$, where $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. I found that the expected value is the infinite series,

$$\frac{1}{10}+\frac{2}{10^2}+\frac{3}{10^3}+\frac{4}{10^4}+\cdots$$

How can I find a closed form formula for this series? Am I supposed to combine the formula for a geometric series and a sequential arithmetic series?

Comment: Differentiate $1+x+x^2+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Probability mass function $10^{-k}$... what about the other $\frac89$? What's $X$ when it isn't one of $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico–geometric_sequence#Infinite_series

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $S=\frac1{10}+\frac2{10^2}+\frac3{10^3}+\cdots.$ We find that
$$\begin{align*}
S-\frac{S}{10} &= \left(\frac1{10}+\frac2{10^2}+\frac3{10^3}+\cdots\right)-\left(\frac0{10}+\frac1{10^2}+\frac2{10^3}+\frac3{10^4}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac1{10}+\frac1{10^2}+\frac1{10^3}+\cdots =\frac{1}9.
\end{align*}$$ So $\frac{9S}{10}=\frac19$ and $S = \frac{10}{81}$ follows.

Comment: Song. Very nice.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to evaluate the sum

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{10^k}$$

The calculus approach is to consider the function

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

By differentiating this with respect to $x$, we find that

$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}\implies f'(1/10)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{10^{k-1}}=10S$$

Thus, we can compute $S$ by taking the derivative of $f$.

The algebraic approach I think is much more clever, but much tricker to see since it doesn't use the power of calculus. We start with the fact that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10^k}=\frac{1}{9}$$

(can you show this?) Then, we rewrite the sum as

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{10^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k-1}{10^k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10^k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k-1}{10^k}+\frac{1}{9}$$

The remaining sum may be reindexed to start at $1$, giving us

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{10^{k+1}}+\frac{10}{9}=\frac{1}{10}S+\frac{1}{9}$$

Either way, we compute may compute $S$ from these formulae, and you may use whichever feels more comfortable.